# Добавить ключ и значение в каждую запись

Tags: php

Как добавить к каждой записи массива ключ и значение, если изначально не известно количество записей?

*Оновление*

Вот у меня есть массив

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [account] => [address] => [category] => send [amount] => -0.019 [fee] => -0.001 [confirmations] => 37 [blockhash] => [blockindex] => 5 [blocktime] => [txid] => [time] => [timereceived] => ) [1] => Array ( [account] => [address] => [category] => send [amount] => -0.019 [fee] => -0.001 [confirmations] => 0 [txid] => [time] => [timereceived] => ) )
```

*Обновление 2*

Мне нужно к каждой строке добавить `[type] => CCC`, чтобы получилось так:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [account] => [address] => [category] => send [amount] => -0.019 [fee] => -0.001 [confirmations] => 37 [blockhash] => [blockindex] => 5 [blocktime] => [txid] => [time] => [timereceived] => [type] => CCC )
[1] => Array ( [account] => [address] => [category] => send [amount] => -0.019 [fee] => -0.001 [confirmations] => 0 [txid] => [time] => [timereceived] => [type] => CCC ) )
```

Comment: И количество этих строк не ограничено.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, пожалуйста, используйте кнопку {} редактора для форматирования кода. Или вы у себя в коде тоже так валите массивы?

Comment: Ну в общем решил проблему другим способом.

Comment: @RattleSneyk, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = array('foo' => 'bar'); // when you create 
$a['Title'] = 'blah'; // later
```

Comment: Это добавит именно запись массива.
А мне нужно к каждой записи массива добавлять.

Comment: $a = array('foo' => array(1,2,3));
$a['foo'][count($a['foo'])] = 4;

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, когда вставляешь в код массив, делай это не с помощью `var_dump` или `print_r`, а [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php) - тогда этот массив будет всем понятен

Во-вторых, обычно длина массива никому не известна :) Это типовой случай. Массивы могут быть с целочисленными индексами, с литеральными индексами или смешанные. Если однозначно известно, что индексы только целочисленные, то можно использовать [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) с счётчиком

```
<?php
    // итерация for + использование целочисленного счётчика списка
    $count = count($array); 
    foreach($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        $array[$i]['type'] = 'CCC';
    }
?>
```

Есть ещё морально устаревшие варианты с использованием `reset`, `next`, `key`, `value`.

Но проще всего и универсальнее использовать итератор [`foreach`][3], который не зависит от типа данных ключей

```
<?php
    // итерация foreach + ключ + использование указателя на элемент списка
    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
        $value['type'] = 'CCC';
    }
?>
```

Последний вариант так удобен, что про обычный [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) хочется забыть. Но не забывают, потому что `for` с целочисленным индексом работает быстрее, а также он может содержать комбинации выражений в блоке инициализации, проверки и приращения индекса.